# JObject Select Token Null Reference Exception c#

Tags: c#, json, asmx

Folks, I am having a hard time making this work, I have a asmx webservice which is accessed from android and when I send the json string to the webservice the SelectToken method I call to get the first node throws a NRE, but this issue doesnt happen when I debug the code from within VS using the json string manually. It only happens when its called from outside.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<ProductDetail> getAllProductsNearMeJson(String ProductRequest)
{
    JObject obj = new JObject();
    String products = null;

    obj = JObject.Parse(ProductRequest);    

    JToken jtk = null;
    jtk = obj.SelectToken("ProductRequest",false);

    products = jtk.ToString();
    var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductMobileRequest>(products);

     //TESTE ONLY
    //var request = new ProductMobileRequest();
    //request.PRODUCT_LAT = "-30.1135";
    //request.PRODUCT_LNG = "-51.2441";
    //TESTE ONLY

    var lat = request.PRODUCT_LAT;
    var lng = request.PRODUCT_LNG;
    List<ProductDetail> pdrList = null;
    ProductMobileResponse response = new ProductMobileResponse();
    try
    {
        response = _productService.ListMobileNearLocation(request, lat, lng);
        if (response.PRODUCTS.Count > 0)
            response.STATUS = true;
        else
            response.STATUS = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.STATUS = false;
        //response.EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = ex.Message;
    }

    if (response.STATUS)
    {
                       return response.PRODUCTS;
    }
    else
    {
        return pdrList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the whole point is: what is the value of ProductRequest parameter?

Comment: {"ProductRequest":"{\"PRODUCT_BATHS\":\"\",\"PRODUCT_GARAGE\":\"\",\"PAGE_SIZE\":\"20\",\"PRODUCT_ROOMS\":\"\",\"SEARCH_TYPE\":\"\",\"PRODUCT_MIN_VAL\":\"\",\"PAGE_INDEX\":\"1\",\"PRODUCT_SELLER\":\"\",\"PRODUCT_FURNITURE\":\"\",\"PRODUCT_TYPE\":\"\",\"PRODUCT_LNG\":\"-51.2434\",\"PRODUCT_LAT\":\"-30.1133\",\"PRODUCT_MAX_VAL\":\"\",\"PRODUCT_CITY\":\"\"}"}

Comment: Can you post that json string inside your question? It is hard to copy it from the comment because there are some special characters and it is not clear if those come from the SO or from your original string

Comment: Also the rest of your code is irrelevant, if you are sure that the `NullReferenceException` comes from line `jtk = obj.SelectToken("ProductRequest",false);`. My advice is to cut the question only to the relevant code parts.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by modifying the signature of my method to take a complex object instead, so there is no need to select tokens in a JObject, however if you are passing a Json over HTTP you need to decorate the complex type in C# as this:

```
public class myclass
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name {get;set;]
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<ProductDetail> getAllProductsNearMeJson(MyClass ProductRequest)
{
  //do your stuff here and return a List<T>
}
```

this way .net parses your json string as a valid MyClass type when method is called.